# 3 colored squares in each row and column of a 7×7 grid

Tags: mathematics

Imagine we have a 7×7 square, and we want to color it a way such that each row and column has exactly 3 colored squares. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why are there so many downvotes ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the only solution, but I got this on the first try.
X = colored square.

> [image]

Comment: Yes, you can colour any three rot13(oebxra qvntbanyf) for a solution. You can then reorder the rows or columns too.